# jQuery fadeTo in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, fadeto

I did some research regarding getting the `fadeTo` function to work in IE8 where a `div` has the CSS position set to `relative`.  I found a lot of answers saying there is a workaround by adding `filter:inherit` and `opacity:inherit`
I have tried using this and it does not work in IE8, works fine in Chrome and FF.  I have submitted test snippet code (just change the link to your jQuery library location) just copy and paste the whole thing and test on your end.
Essentially I am trying to fade all content in the HTML body tag and not just specific elements.

Thanks people

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#div_item_added{
  display: block;
  margin: 9px;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #9B9A9A;
  height: 80px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
overflow: hidden;
}

#div-test{
  position: relative;
  filter: inherit;
  opacity: inherit;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" >
function fade(){
  $("#div-body").fadeTo(1000, 0.1);
}
function unfade(){
  $("#div-body").fadeTo(1000, 1);
}
</script>
</head>

<div id="div-body">
<body>
<div id="div-test">
  <table border="1" style="background-color:#FF0000;">
  <tr>
  <td>A table that should Fade when html body fades</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</div>

<div id="div_item_added">
<table border="0" style="border:border-collapse;">
<tr>
<td>Some text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="button" value="Fade Background" onclick="fade();">
<input type="button" value="Un-Fade Background" onclick="unfade();">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Fading in IE8 is always going to be hit-and-miss due to the poor support for it in the browser. jQuery makes it easier to write the code, but it can't do anything about the underlying shortcomings in the browser itself.

Comment: Most of us do hate MS browsers for their lack of compliance with standards but surely there must be a simple solution rather then fading all divs separately within the <body> tag.  If I was to change these two lines: $("#div-body").fadeTo(1000, 0.1); and $("#div-body").fadeTo(1000, 0.1); to the div inside the body like this $("#div-test").fadeTo(1000, 0.1); etc. it works fine, but this is specifying that particular div and not all content inside <body> tag

Comment: In fact the modern IE versions like IE10 are actually pretty good when it comes to standards. The old versions are problematic though, particularly when it comes to stuff like this. There's a reason why people didn't do fade out effects in the browser when IE8 was the top dog. Fading works pretty well in modern browsers, including IE, but that doesn't mean IE8 is miraculously going to gain new features. The sooner IE8 fades into obscurity, the better.

Comment: hehe... "**fades** into obscurity".... see what I did there?  ;-)  (pun not intended... honest!)